# Integration test through message broker

Tags: java, maven, junit, integration-testing, messaging

There are two programs that are communicating using message broker and I want to cover some interactions between them using integration tests.

So I want to write the integration test that will use JUnit, in before stage want to run the external program and in "after" stage it should be cleaned up.

Is there a good way to do this, or I'm just going the wrong path?

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution?

Comment: Yes, 8 years later I'm using Kafka test containers for my tests and I'm pretty satisfied.